# Data path "/styles/0" must be object

Tags: angular

Suddenly,when restarted my laptop and run my angular project I started getting these errors in my vs-code and I don't where is the problem in vscode or angular.
`Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "/styles/0" must be object. Data path "/styles/0" must match pattern "\.(?:css|scss|sass|less|styl)$". Data path "/styles/0" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.`
I am using angular 14 and vs-code ide. Anyone please help me in resolving this error.

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Open.fit": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/open.fit",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/@mobiscroll/angular/dist/css/mobiscroll.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "5145d200-acc8-4835-bc5d-113730f2d3a8"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you checked your paths under styles array?

Comment: You seem to have 2 styles blocks.. doesn’t look right?

Comment: I have checked on my other projects. They too have 2 style blocks and they are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error relates to the first entry of the `styles` array:

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", // <- Problem here
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css",
  "./node_modules/@mobiscroll/angular/dist/css/mobiscroll.min.css"
],
```

The array expects only entries that match the pattern:
`\.(?:css|scss|sass|less|styl)$`. Notice that the first entry does not match this pattern (you can verify this on any regex testing website like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)). These pattern ensures that only files that have styles are used.

As such, this entry should be removed and the error should disappear.
I would also check what is the purpose of this file and if its needed or not. If it is needed I would move it to the `scripts` array.

Note: styling may be done via a script, like bootstrap, but in those cases, it should be present in the `scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer**

In your `"Open.fit/architect/build/styles"` definition in the 0th index (judging from the location hint `"styles/0"` extracted from the error message) you have an entry ending in `jquery.min.js`. This does not match the regular expression pattern `"\.(?css|scss|sass|less)$"`, because your entry does end in `.js`, which is not a valid style sheet.

**Another example and explanation**

I encountered a similar problem when upgrading from angular 13 to 14. the error read

```
Data path "/styles/3" must be object.
Data path "/styles/3" must match pattern "\.(?css|scss|sass|less)$".
Data path "/styles/3" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

I found out `"styles/3"` refers to the styles definition in `angular.js` and the `3` to the fourth index (3, but 0-based). At 0 based index 3 there was an entry `"node_modules/@angular/material"` which worked in past versions (or at least didn’t raise an error).

I replaced this entry with

```
"node_modules/@angular/material/_index.scss",
"node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss"
```

This brought me past this error, so that it compiled and the webpage showed up. **Hint**: I don't know if this is the correct replacement, but to me it sounded like the most logical one.

**Techniques to finding the problem or solution**: If unsure remove all entries in `styles` section, then try your favourite command (`ng serve` or `npm start`) to see if it compiles. Then add one entry and try compiling again. Repeat until it fails. Then you find the entry in question and you can correct it according to the error message.